# multiplying a non-square number to get a square

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a theory that the only way how can I get a square from a non-square is to multiply it by some power of itself. For example 3 multiplied by 27 gives 81.

Is this always true? If yes, how would one go about proving that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not true: $$3 \cdot 12 = 36 = 6^2$$ but $12$ is not a power of $3$.

---

What can be said is this, as a consequence of [unique factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic):

> If $3s$ is a perfect square for some $s$, then it is necessary that $3^{2k + 1}$ is a divisor of $s$ for some $k$. That is, an odd power of $3$ divides $s$.

In the previous case, $k = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$6\cdot54=(2\cdot3)(2\cdot3^3)=(2\cdot3^2)^2=18^2=324$.  The answer to your question lies in the Unique Prime Factorization Theorem.  In order for a number to be a square, the power of all the primes that divide that number must be divisible by two, so for two non-square numbers  to multiply to a square they must have the same primes with odd power.

Comment: So, a non-square multiplied by a square can never be a square, right?